# laravel route() generate link with different domain name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have defined my routes in laravel web.php file like this.

```
 Route::get('/landing')->name('landing');
```

I can generate links for this route like this:

```
route('landing')
```

and the result link in my html files is sth like "mysite.com/landing"
is there any way to generate links for another domain name.
I mean by calling the route('landing') the result be sth like "othersite.com/landing"

Comment: for other domain its not possible but you can do this for you site sub domain .....

Answer (score 1):

By using an anonymous function in your route you can achieve this.

```
Route::name('landing-outside')->get('landing-outside', function(){
    return redirect('http://my-other-domain.com/landing');
});

<a href='{{ route('landing-outside') }}'>Link to my-other-domain</a>
```